# Get the client's IP address

Tags: asp.net-core, ip-address

Previously in other version of asp.net, I used these properties of `HttpRequest`:

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
Request.UserHostAddress
```

How can I achieve the same in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```cs
private IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
public Foo(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
{
    _accessor = accessor;
}
```

Now you get IP address this way"

```cs
var ip = _accessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

Comment: I can't get this work on DNX (full clr), any sugestions? RemoteIpAddress property is null in my app...

Comment: @MarcinZablocki You have to register it in Startup:
`services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Answer (score 8):

`HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` is the property you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

And you can use Request

```
var GetIp = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It works very well.

```
var ip = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```