# Deploy ASP.NET 5 on Azure WebApps behind IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I have a problem with obtaining IP address of client who sent a request to a ASP.NET 5 application hosted on Azure WebApps.

My project uses ASP.NET 5 + MVC6 and runs on full CLR runtime (not CoreCLR). I've searched through the net for the answer, but haven't found any solution.

Using sugggestion from [Get the client's IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359109/get-the-clients-ip-address-in-asp-net-5)
I've tried:

```
HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress
```

but the properties from HttpContext.Connection are all either false or null, so no luck here.

I've noticed the following: when I run my app via Visual Studio with IIS Express, the IP from `Connection.RemoteIpAddress` is available.
Property is null when i run **dnx web** via command line. It seems that azure runs my app in the on dnx, not IIS.

So my question is:
**How to configure and deploy project to Azure WebApps, so it will run behind IIS and therefore HttpContext.Connection will have it's values filled ?**

My current configuration (excerpt of project.json):

```
(...)
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
      },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
      },
(...)
```

and the Configure method of Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{  
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    //rest of the method...

}
```

Comment: I've answered the first part of the question (IIS/Kestrel). Regarding the client IP, the package Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler and the middleware UseIISPlatformHandler() is supposed to forward the client IP according to https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/issues/189. Are you sure to use it?

Comment: This redirects the IP on my local instance but not on deployed Azure Web Site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Web App always uses IIS.

However, for ASP.NET 5 code, IIS is configured to use HttpPlatformHandler to redirect requests to Kestrel, the ASP.NET 5 web server.
This is the way to run ASP.NET 5 application from ASP.NET Beta 8.
You will see that configuration by opening your web.config file.

References :

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx
- https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/69

There are some open issues related to obtaining client IP adress when using Kestrel, and they seem to be resolved in RC2 release:

- https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/commit/e9a60610236c53e9518fe80ccf75f14b7e5d02f8
- https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/359
- https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/17

Comment: Then you have the post beta8 behavior I've described: IIS is used as a reverse proxy to send requests to Kestrel.

Comment: It might be related to this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/359

Comment: This might be related to the following issue, planned to be fixed for RC2: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/359