# How to get the remote client IP address in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the remote Ip address

On Startup.cs

```
 app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

Then I use `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()` to retrieve the IP. I publish to the hosting and it returns wrong IP, somewhere in Hongkong instead of my real IP in other Asian country.  I checked with a few pc in different location, all shows wrong IP.

Comment: IP address to exact location is not reliable.

Comment: Few other people also have asked same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359109/get-the-clients-ip-address If I am correct you are not looking for ipaddress to location mapping.